# Ajax Get Requests inquiry

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, get, roblox

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://www.roblox.com/My/GroupAdmin.aspx?gid=148530",
  data: {   javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$GroupMemberAdminPane$dlMembers_Footer$ctl02$ctl00','')        }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
        $(msg).find('.member-name-container').children('[title]').each(function() {
          console.log( $(this ).text() )
   var g = $(msg ).text()
  });
});
```

How exactly do I make this log the data I want it to find after it does the postback?
Its clearly supposed to log in console.
I'm trying to find all the usernames in this group on ROBLOX.
Help as fast as possible, really need to finish this project.
How do I fix this?

Comment: well, nobody can help you with this, if you don't show us what is send back by your `asp` script. just do `console.log(msg)` in your `done()` function and tell us what you get.

Comment: If you have any more questions ask here.

Comment: It logs the entire webpage's HTML.

I need it to log what im asking for after the postback happens.

I'm very new to ajax and asp.net

Comment: like i already said, do `console.log(msg)` inside your `done()` function and tell us what it is returning.

Comment: It returns the names, from the first page of people, its just it has a ton of html/css around the rest of it..

Answer (score 0):

well the `$()` in `jQuery` is a selector which applies to `classes`, `ids` and much more in your `DOM`. you can't parse a text with just putting it inside `$()` - that's not how it works since you don't have your resulting `html` in your `DOM`. so you have to parse it like text, not like it was in your `DOM`.